# Tests for Equality of Distribution for High Dimensional Outcomes

Tags: hypothesis-testing, high-dimensional

Suppose I have two groups, $A$ and $B$, and a null hypothesis which states that the distribution of some high-dimensional random vector $\mathbf X$ is equal across the two groups, i.e. $\mathbf X | A \overset{d}= \mathbf X | B$, but does not otherwise place paraemtric restrictions on the distribution of $\mathbf X$. My question is whether there is any literature one how one might go about "optimally" testing this hypothesis.

To try to make my question a bit more concrete, an initial idea I had in mind is that given such a null hypothesis, we have that for any function $f$, $\mathbb E[f(\mathbf X) | A] = \mathbb E[f(\mathbf X)|B]$. One idea might trying to define some sense in which there is an optimal function $f$ from the perspective of maximizing statistical power in rejecting the null hypothesis and whether the optimal choice of $f$ might itself be feasibly estimated from the data.

Perhaps the idea above is not the right approach, but hopefully, it gives a flavor for the type of paper I am looking for.

Comment: A well-used approach is to compute p-values for each component, then use the minimum of all such p-values as the test statistic. Then use permutation sampling to find the correct p-value for the omnibus test. It is called the "Minp test," and there are various published optimality properties.